# Confidence intervals after one-to-many matching - number of degrees of freedom

Tags: confidence-interval, propensity-scores, matching

I have propensity score matched data after 1-to-3 matching. I am trying to use the code from the answer to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37973240/

The question is: what number of degrees of freedom am I to take? Must I take the overall number of matched observations as in the answer, or am I to take the sum of all the weights (the doubled number of matched treated subjects)?

Comment: It is unclear to me what it is you are asking here. I take that you have some observational data and have used propensity score matching to estimate the average treatment effect on the treated (ATT)? If so, is it a confidence interval for ATT that you are after? If that is the case, then the Matching package in R has an implementation of confidence intervals based on Theorem 7 from Abadie & Imbens (2006).

Abadie, A., & Imbens, G. W. (2006). Large sample properties of matching estimators for average treatment effects, *Econometrica*, 74(1), 235-267.

Comment: @Phil Thank you! I do not mean estimating ATE or ATT. I want to build some estimates for a number of covariates after matching. I will see the theorem.

Comment: If estimating the ATE or ATT is not the main interest, then I don't think the reference I proposed is what you are looking at. What do you mean by "estimates for a number of covariates after matching"?

Comment: @Phil I have some covariates, whose means after matching, I want to estimate (for all the matched observations, for treated, and for control ones). So I need to build somehow the confidence intervals.

Comment: Why not bootstrap your sample? (You might want to considering using as unit of analysis the 1-to-3 quadruplet.)